# How to show all image product in description product

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-images, product-view

I use Magento 1.9.1
I want to show all image product in description, because it have protect by watermark
I have google search "how to", but code not working

This code not work, when i insert to **description.html**, all content after code not show, and image not show

```
<?php $_images
=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages();?><?php if($_images){?><?php $i=0;foreach($_images as $_image){ $i++;?> <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product,'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(108,90);?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel());?>" title="<?php $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel());?>" /><?php }?><?php }?>
```

When I use this code, it only show 1 image first:

```
<?php echo '<img id="image" src="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image')->keepAspectRatio(true)->keepFrame(false)->resize(680, null).'"/>';?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<?php
    $collection = $this->getProduct()->getMediaGalleryImages();
    foreach ($collection as $_image): 
?>
    <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile())->resize(300); ?>" width="300" height="300" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_image->getLabel()) ?>" />
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Result (base theme):
[image]